# Run Impala Refresh from Hive or Webhdfs

Tags: curl, hive, impala, webhdfs

I am working with some tables on Imapala and querying that using a jdbc HIVE driver. I need to run a Refresh on some tables before extract data (or configure Impala to run it automatically). When i try to run `refresh tablename` by the jdbc driver i can't (because in HIVE this command doesn't exists - i think). I have tried to write a simple impala-shell script (`refresh tablename`) and run using curl like this `curl -i -L "http://<server>:50070/webhdfs/v1/<path to sh file>?op=OPEN"` it doesn't work too. Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
INVALIDATE METADATA databsename.tablename
```

Comment: What does this do? A quick explanation would make this a much stronger answer

Answer (score 0):

@Andisu : if you want to do a refresh through **Impala-Shell** then run the following command:

```
impala-shell -d db_NAME -q "REFRESH tablename";
```

-q: The impala-shell interpreter immediately exits after processing the statement within double quotes.
If you do **REFRESH**, that means `new data files` were added to the HDFS location of the table by you, so the metadata of block location of these files must be loaded to  **Impala Daemon Coordinator**.